# H2O.apply python function seems to be broken

Tags: python, apply, h2o

I'm having trouble with H2O's apply function in Python 3.6.1 under anaconda 4.3.22.  I'm running version H2O 3.10.4.4 on Windows 10.  I suspect this may be a bug (or else there's a bug in the documentation.)

I took this example snippet from H2O booklet, page 14:
http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/booklets/PythonBooklet.pdf

```
df5 = h2o.H2OFrame.from_python(np.random.randn(100,4).tolist(), column_names=list("ABCD"))
df5.apply(lambda x: x.mean(na_rm=True))
```

And I got the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-e45989298b6f> in <module>()
      1 df5 = h2o.H2OFrame.from_python(np.random.randn(100,4).tolist(), column_names=
      2 list("ABCD"))
----> 3 df5.apply(lambda x: x.mean(na_rm=True))

C:\cygwin64\usr\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h2o\frame.py in apply(self, fun, axis)
   2756         assert_is_type(fun, FunctionType)
   2757         assert_satisfies(fun, fun.__name__ == "<lambda>")
-> 2758         res = _bytecode_decompile_lambda(fun.__code__)
   2759         return H2OFrame._expr(expr=ExprNode("apply", self, 1 + (axis == 0), *res))
   2760 

C:\cygwin64\usr\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h2o\astfun.py in _bytecode_decompile_lambda(co)
     86                 raise ValueError("unimpl: op in hasjrel")
     87             elif op in haslocal:
---> 88                 args.append(co.co_varnames[oparg])  # LOAD_FAST
     89             elif op in hascompare:
     90                 args.append(cmp_op[oparg])  # COMPARE_OP

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: "anaconda3" implies Python 3? (It might be useful to give the exact Python version.) I wonder if that code is only for Python 2.7?

Comment: I updated the version info.  I doubt this is a Python 2.7 vs. 3.x problem because of the error "tuple index out of range", but it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

That code in the Python booklet is outdated -- the argument name changed to become compatible with Pandas, but unfortunately it was not made backwards compatible (that's a bug and I opened a ticket to fix that [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4670)).  The argument is now `skipna`.  Here is the correct way to do it:

```
df5 = h2o.H2OFrame.from_python(np.random.randn(100,4).tolist(), column_names=list("ABCD"))
df5.apply(lambda x: x.mean(skipna=False))
```

Comment: I'm still getting "tuple index out of range" error.  (This error message is also unhelpful...)

Comment: It looks like it's working in Python 2.7 and 3.5 but not 3.6.  I have filed a bug report here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4672